# How can i change userpic on the start screen?

Tags: display, user-interface, user

Is it possible to change default blue pic to smth another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Settings >> User Accounts

Unlock in upper right with password.

Click on the picture placeholder

Navigate to the picture you want to use, and you're all set!

https://youtu.be/mFXM00hJxnk